# How to manually add partition details into hive metastore tables?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

In my HDFS, I've partitioned data by **date** and **event_id**, and have about 1.4 million parquet files. Today, to analyze the data in Apache Spark, I use `spark.read.parquet("/path/to/root/")`. This takes about 30 minutes to list the files, I have to do this every time, and it's getting annoying.

Now, I want to setup an external table, using MySQL as the Hive Metastore. I'm currently facing the know issue where discovering all 1.4 partitions taking forever. As we all known `MSCK REPAIR TABLE my_table` is out of the picture. I instead generated a long query (*about 400 MB*) that contains this query like this

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD 
  PARTITION (date = 'YYYY-MM-DD', event_id = "<some value>") LOCATION ''
  PARTITION (date = 'YYYY-MM-DD', event_id = "<some value>") LOCATION ''
  PARTITION (date = 'YYYY-MM-DD', event_id = "<some value>") LOCATION ''
  ...
  PARTITION (date = 'YYYY-MM-DD', event_id = "<some value>") LOCATION ''
  PARTITION (date = 'YYYY-MM-DD', event_id = "<some value>") LOCATION ''
```

It has been 3 hours, and it still has only processed less than 100,000 partitions. I have observed a few things:

1. Spark does one partition at a time.
2. Spark seems to check each path for existence.

All these adds to the long running time. I've searched, and haven't been able to find how to disable both operations.

So, I want to manually perform SQL operations against the MySQL database and table for the Hive metastore, to create and manage the tables. I've looked but have been unable to figure out how to manually manage those tables. Please, does anyone know how to do that? Specifically, I want the following:

1. How can can create an external table with partitions, by making direct entries into the Hive metastore tables?
2. How can I manage an External table partition by making direct upsert queries against the Hive metastore tables?

Is there a good resource I could use to learn about the backing tables in the metastore. I feel doing the inserts manually would be much much faster. Thank you.

Comment: Who owns the "partitions"?  Hive?  Or MySQL?  In MySQL, partitioning is rarely a performance boost.  Show us the table structure.

Comment: @RickJames, I don't think I understand your question. I generate, and partition the parquet files. I want to use a hive metastore to track the table and partition information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the core problem here is that you have too many partitions. Partitioning should generally be done on a low-cardinality column (something with a relatively small number of distinct values, compared to the total number of records). Typically you want to err on the side of having a smaller number of large files, rather than a large number of small files.

In your example, `date` is probably a good partitioning column, assuming there are many records for each date. If there are a large number of distinct values for `event_id`, that's not a great candidate for partitioning. Just keep it as an unpartitioned column.

An alternative to partitioning for a high-cardinality column is *bucketing*. This groups similar values for the bucketed column so they're in the same file, but doesn't split each value across separate files. The [AWS Athena docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/bucketing-vs-partitioning.html) have a good overview of the concept.

Comment: If an external table (_another process creating the files_) how can I inform Spark the data files are bucketd... That is, each file contains data for a particular `event_id`? (_keep in mind distinct number of `event_id` varies_) Also, does Spark index the values for `event_id` for each bucket? Will `MSCK REPAIR` do so?

Comment: @ThatGuy Bucketing is a performance optimization that can help avoid data shuffles in certain situations, but it adds some complexity. Before going down that path I'd try just keeping event_id as a regular column in each record (not a partition column), and see if you can consolidate the small files into fewer large files.

Comment: Each file in a given partition of `event_date` + `event_id` is about 1GB parquet files, so not really small files. I could try regenerating the files where they are partitioned on `event_date` (each folder), then bucketed on `event_id` (each file within a date is for a particular `event_id`). If I do so, how does Spark know which `event_id` is within a given bucket?

Comment: The bucketing schema is part of the table metadata. The idea here is to make joins more efficient: joining two tables on a common (bucketed) key means it knows in advance which files contain the records. But you might not need that, I'd try just removing the event_id partition and keeping it as a regular column instead. Partitions are like an index, if there's one partition per file then it sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by "_The bucketing schema is part of the table metadata._"? 

If I create an External table in spark, pointing it to the folder that contains my parquet files, does Spark do an initial scan to determine what value for `event_id` is for each file? (_assuming I bucket, each file containing only values of specific `event_id`_)

Additionally, what do you mean by "_if there's one partition per file then it sort of defeats the purpose_"?

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue with statistics auto-gathering. As a workaround, switch off hive.stats.autogather before recovering partitions.

1. Switch-off statistics auto-gathering:

   `set hive.stats.autogather=false;`
2. Run MSCK REPAIR or ALTER TABLE RECOVER PARTITIONS.

If you need statistics to be fresh, you can execute ANALYZE separately for new partitions only.

Related tickets are [HIVE-18743](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18743), [HIVE-19489](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19489), [HIVE-17478](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17478)